# Where did my portal key go?

Tags: ingress

I was running around capturing portals like a good little Enlightened, creating links between portals in a small area. I hacked one portal and acquired the portal key. I then ran up the road to another portal, hacked and deployed to it and linked it to the first portal.

When I tried to link a third portal to the first one, it said that I no longer had the key for it.

Does the key get used up if you link to it? I thought once you had a key, it never went away unless you dropped it. Is this correct?

Comment: The portal was still there.... but the key was not in my inventory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Linking and creating fields with the portals consumes the keys.

Also I advise drop hacking: If you already have a key to a portal drop the key before hacking again then pick it up afterwards and you'll have two keys to the same portal.

Comment: Jeez, that was never mentioned in any tutorial. Is it when you create a link that the key is consumed, or only if you create a field with it?

Comment: Linking the portals

Comment: As a variation on drop hacking, you can place keys inside a capsule instead of dropping the item